# Erase my image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I have menu structure as show [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/3TDF3/).

All item have a background img. But when hover back, hide my menu item img. Because, js code isn't valid this img but i don't know how can i solve this.

I want, still javascript fade effect but don't hide my img.

Normally:

[image]

Problem: (Hover and hover-out)

[image]

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we can't see you background images unless you put them online and link them correctly in your CSS.

Comment: Please state what you want vs. what is happening more clearly. Sorry to say but your english is not good, and is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to fade the background on hover, and restore it on hover-out, then use the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bg;
$("#right_menu a").mouseover(function() {
    bg = $(this).css('background-color');
     $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#002C6A'},500);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:bg},500);
});       
});​
```

If you want to use image then change background-color to background.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/3TDF3/2/

---

**UPDATE:** Just revisited code. Much of the problem is that css class is set on **li**, while modifications a being made on **a**

You are setting background-image to li, but animating a. Therefore the background of li gets hidden with new background of a.

Change `$("#right_menu a").mouseover` to `$("#right_menu li").mouseover`

Comment: Thank you but i cannot see my img hover out.

Comment: Working with background-color for testing purpose. If you change the background-color to background or background-image, it should work.

Comment: Saw it. You will need to switch the url from 'background' to 'background-image'. Then store that in a variable (eg: "bg2 = $(this).css('background-image');") in mouseover callback, and set it to appropriate css attribute on mouseout callback using "$(this).css('background-image','bg2');".

Comment: The problem with showing it on jsfiddle is I need images. and loading from urls is a pain. Will still try to do so with a small example.

Comment: Got it!
Much of the problem is coming due to the css style class being applied to the <li> while the function is getting attached to <a>. Change '$("#right_menu a").mouseover' to '$("#right_menu li").mouseover' ... Should do wonders!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12441/discussion-between-playmaker-and-user1213807)

Answer (score 0):

Try using background color instead of image. When mouse is hovers away from the link, set the background color to the previous value. Using image where background color seems to be sufficient looks like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var backgroundimage = $(this).css("background-image");//store it in a variable
    $("#right_menu a").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#002C6A'},500);
        $(this).css("background-image","none");//remove it
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#fff'},500);
        $(this).css("background-image",backgroundimage );//bring it back
    });       
});​
```

Comment: lol what will $(this) refer to? You will have to have in the function

Comment: he just would have to do $(this).parent.parent until he finds the the node which have the background image

Comment: Try it on jsfiddle (replacing to work wit background color for time being). It won't work. Or simply just call an alert which will give value of 'backgroundimage' variable on hover. Won't work. This is because you are trying to set the value on document load. 'this' refers to nothing.